# Add fullwidth background to related products

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, extend, full-width

I am trying to add a full-width background to the related products on my magento 2 site extending the luma theme. the problem i am having is that the background is being applied but the left/right is then pushing the products out of view

in my less I have

```
.bg-white-fog {
    background: @color-white-fog;
}

.hundred-vw {
        margin-left: calc(50% - 720px);
        margin-right: calc(50% - 720px);
}
```

in my items.phtml I have added the section tag to wrap it

```
<?php if ($exist):?>
  <section class="bg-white-fog similar-products hundred-vw">
    <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
        <?php if ($type == 'related'): ?>
            <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="block-title title">
        <h3 class="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading">
        <?php if ($type == 'related' && $canItemsAddToCart): ?>
        <div class="block-actions">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Check items to add to the cart or') ?>
            <button type="button" class="action select" role="select-all"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('select all') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
            <ol class="products list items product-items">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>

                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                            <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                    ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                            type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= ($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score -1):

To providing full width you have to move that particular element from `main` `referenceContainer`

Use `<move>` layout instruction for example :

```
<move element="name.of.your.related.product.block" destination="page.bottom.container" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```